# Nginx - Reverse proxy all requests starting with a keyword

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to redirect all requests starting with "mydomain/_dash" to "mydomain:8050/_dash" so that "mydomain/_dash-component-suites/" redirects to "mydomain:8050/_dash-component-suites/". I have added the following directive but it doesn't work. Plus, I also want to maintain the headers of each request.

```
location /_dash(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    
    proxy_pass http://analytics:8050/_dash(*);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions:

```
location ~ /_dash(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

    client_max_body_size 0;
    
    proxy_pass http://analytics:8050/_dash$1;
  }
```